# Getting SES mode to act somewhat like a regular spreadsheet

Tags: spreadsheet

So I have been working in an office that deals a ton with spreadsheets (mostly non-numeric data). With some things SES mode is a perfect alternative to the standard Excel sheet. I have found one thing that is a huge limitation so far though. I have tried, but cannot find a way to copy formulas smartly in Emacs SES. For example, if the formula in cell C1 is (+ A1 B1), I would like to be able to copy the formula from C1 into C2 and have the formula be (+A2 B2) instead of (+ A1 B1). Also, a way to fill in series in columns would be great.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "a way to fill in series in columns"? What precisely are you wanting to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

> if the formula in cell C1 is (+ A1 B1), I would like to be able to copy the formula from C1 into C2 and have the formula be (+A2 B2) instead of (+ A1 B1).

That's how it *does* work, though.

If I set a formula `(+ A1 B1)` in cell C1, then mark and copy that cell, and yank it into cell C2, the resulting formula in C2 is `(+ A2 B2)`.

This is using <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> <kbd><right></kbd> <kbd>M-w</kbd> to mark and copy the formula, and <kbd>C-y</kbd> to yank it.

Comment: Seriously? That's what I have been doing, and it doesn't seem to be working for me. This is both on Debian at home and Emacs for Windows at work.

Comment: Which version of Emacs is this? I tested in 25.2. I feel like this is how it always worked, but I rarely use SES, so I can't say for certain.

Comment: The version in Debian I am using is 24.5 (Debian stretch). And the version that I "installed" at work is the 25.2 64 bit version from the Gnu FTP website. I feel stupid now though. I wasn't copying the cell itself, I was copying the formula from the minibuffer. It's working just fine now. Of course it would just kill the formula itself and not change it when I used C-y to yank. Now that I am working in an office environment, I'm trying to introduce as much free software as I can. I used SES mode for about half the day yesterday. Now that I understand this, I should be able to utilize it more.